# How to begin a function only after a Parse.Object.saveAll or Parse.Promise.when

Tags: parse-platform, promise

I'd like to be able to make my code a little more synchronous starting one function only after Parse has been updated.  I've tried using Parse.Promise.when and Parse.Object.saveAll but it's not quite working the way I'd like as I get inconsistent behavior where the function after then begins before all of my updates have been saved.

I've reviewed the docs several times along with finding sample code on SO and other places but I'm definitely still going wrong somewhere along the way.

```
var goodResults = [1, 3, 5, 7];
var BlueSomething = Parse.Object.extend("something");
var query = new Parse.Query(BlueSomething);
query.find().then(function(results){
     var array = [];
     var array1 = [];
     var array2 = [];
     var array3 = [];

     var resultsToEvaluate = _.map(results, function(n){
                                   return n.get('theGoodResult')});
         var newResults = _.difference(goodResults, resultsToEvaluate);
         var oldResults = _.intersection(goodResults, resultsToEvaluate);

 if(newResults.length > 0){
     _.each(newResults, function(n){
          var new = new BlueSomething();
          new.set('status', n.get('someValue'));
          array.push(new);})}

 if(oldResults.length > 0){
     _.each(oldResults, function(n){
          var count = _.values(n.get('someField')).length;
          var new = new BlueSomething;

          if(count > 5){
             n.set("full", true)
             array1.push(n);

             var new = new BlueSomething();
             new.set("status", n.get('someValue'));
             array2.push(new);
          } else {
             n.set("status", "updated");
             array3.push(n)
          }
        })
      }
      return Parse.Object.saveAll(array, array1, array2, array3)
    }).then(function(){//do other stuff only after the information 
                       //has been saved to Parse});
```

Comment: I see no success/error responses?

Comment: @cYrixmorten, thanks! Now, how do I do that in the saveAll set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using the proper syntax for [saveAll](http://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_saveAll). The first argument should be an array of Parse objects, and the second is a callback. You could concat the arrays into one:

```
return Parse.Object.saveAll(array.concat(array1, array2, array3));
```

Comment: @adamport, thanks! I'm tinkering with using just a single array.  Is that adviseable or is concatination better?

Comment: `saveAll` requires a single array. How you construct that array is up to you.

Comment: @adamport, thanks for the clarity; I was using Parse.Promise.when before and it can take multiple arguments from the examples I've seen, I did not know that saveAll takes a single array.  As suggested by cYrixmorten above, is there a way to call success/error for saveAll?

Comment: Sure, but it's not necessary if you're using promises. You can use a success/error callback, promises, both or neither. Up to you. Cloudcode is different–cloud functions require a `response.success` or `response.error` to be called.

Comment: But even Cloudcode could use promises without success/error callbacks: `Parse.Object.saveAll(array).then(response.success, response.error);`